# Ender 3 S1 fails printing mid ways

Tags: creality-ender-3

I got my first 3D printer, a Creality Ender 3 S1.
I followed the Quick Installation Guide for the initial configuration. I also had to adjust the corners of the bed manually (the very first print ended up as spaghetti).

Now I wanted to try the first print, so I decided to print the "rabbit" that was included as a G-code with the SD card for the printer. I used the filament that was included with the printer.

The problem is that after half of the rabbit body is printed, the nozzle moves the rabbit, and the rest of the print ends like a spaghetti mess and I have to cancel it. This has happened three times now and I don't understand how to fix the problem or what causes it.

Why does the print of the "rabbit" fail mid-way up?
Are there any settings I should adjust? How should I figure out what settings I need?

I used the G-code that was already stored on the SD card, with default settings after adjusting my bed.

Comment: When you say "the nozzle moves the rabbit", do you mean that the model is knocked from the surface of the build plate, i.e. no longer stuck?

Comment: yes, it is no longer stuck, so it is moved on the plate.

Comment: My first thought was that the model did not have sufficient adhesion to the build plate. It seems that you have worked out the problem and things are working out now.

Comment: yes, how do I get better adhesion to the build plate? Probably need a good Z-offset for that? It was strange that it was moved after half the print, it sounds like higher temperature was important to not have filament clogged in the nozzle.

Comment: There are several things that can improve bed adhesion such as you mentioned good Z-offset, ideal bed temp, glue stick/hairspray, etc. Take a look at the other questions here with the tag '[adhesion](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesion)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now got a print of the "rabbit" working.

I did a few things.

- Make sure no parts of the printer are loose. I had to fasten the extruder on the X-axis a bit better. (I think this is an important point)
- I tried a different filament, [AddNorth E-PLA](https://addnorth.com/product/E-PLA/E-PLA%20-%201.75mm%20-%20750g%20-%20Aurora%20Green)

These alone did not solve the problem.
Then I did these adjustments:

- The AddNorth E-PLA filament had a recommended nozzle temperature of 205-225 °C. The default nozzle temperature of Ender 3 S1 seem to be 200 °C. The prints worked better when I set the nozzle temperature to 220 °C (in the beginning of the printing session).
- I tried to use the [Ultimaker Cura](https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura) slicing software, instead of the pre-generated G-code file on the SD card. I used the STL file of the rabbit that was on the SD card as input.

After these adjustments, I finally successfully printed the rabbit.

Comment: The included filament in the package seems not that high in quality. Changing the filament as you did is really helpful. In my case, the first printing is fine, but the part is very sticky to the surface. Really sticky, like it was glued on the bed surface.